# Flow type grandchild inheritance issues

Tags: flowtype

I'm curious as to why this inheritance model succeeds between a base and child, but fails between a child and grandchild. I'm sure there is something I've missed here. The error would make sense to me, if only it *also occurred* between base and child.

```
type BaseType = {
    base: true,
    ...
}

type fnType<O: BaseType> = (options: O) => void;

const base = (options: BaseType) => {
    return;
}

function extend<T: BaseType>(parent: fnType<T>): fnType<T>{
    return (options: T): void => {
        return parent(options);
    }
}

type ChildOneType = {
    ...BaseType,
    one: true,
    ...
};

const childOne = extend<ChildOneType>(base);

type ChildTwoType = {
    ...ChildOneType,
    two: true,
    ...
};

// why fail?
// ---
// Cannot call `extend` with `childOne` bound to `parent` because property `two`
// is missing in `ChildOneType` [1] but exists in `ChildTwoType` [2] in type
// argument `O` [3]. [prop-missing]
const childTwo = extend<ChildTwoType>(childOne);
```

[TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBCAhgM54AquBAvGAN6pjNgBGZeAXGBgE4CueADRMWAOgmoAvumz4wUAHZV8AHgDy3EuRV4AfGDoAKODgwBLOItLd1ASkMGAbnHMATANzoAxldIY2DkMwEzNLay0OXQcaA0YWMF48DH5eRS8ZVCh+RW8LKzA8AA8MPEU3VQpInWo9IxxiJMUMbiVdSr07VuVqDviWJJS0kNN8iLAKLrAXd0cGUQTmQdTFMAamjFCx0jsvBJlMuQIAYQALcxg3dUVKamD+5gkxbVv8EQSrLh4BYQWwJ+kXlQvmsAW850u11ohRKZQqZwuVxuujq7HIu1kdwRlwoCDgunufye2KRr1+CQweO4fEE73EkikQOAwDACFOWAUxAuAH5UMywABaIV8lnHYiKRRwMHEGAwMAAA2KpXK8tZ5gwpwV4MRUNVrDgOTcPDgCvWZQwerw3mI-HIa14pjwvGwCspcHlIrA5lIYAAtt7SOZFABzL2reUkqG6VUAbQAjABdNj8ALFb0YH1BhUk3H46ixgBMSazR09jWD-F95oV6ljAGYE2IwDGcA6cAL-aRAyGE8C-GCIW5c8ElXDVDm8SijNrITddkA)